# Python re.split and re.findall: grouping and capturing

Tags: python, regex

I have strings like `"00:00:00 Segment 1 00:20:00 Segment 2 8:00:00 Segment 3"` and `"00:00 Segment 1 20:0 Segment 2"` and want to use `re.split()` and `re.findall()` to find all the timestamps and segment names. But I am having problem to achieve optional group without the capturing effect. Here are what I got:

```
str_1 = "00:00:00 Segment 1 00:20:00 Segment 2 8:00:00 Segment 3"
str_2 = "00:00 Segment 1 20:0 Segment 2"

re.findall(r'\d\d?:\d\d?:\d\d?', str_1)
=>  ['00:00:00', '00:20:00', '8:00:00']

re.split(r'\d\d?:\d\d?:\d\d?', str_1)
=> ['', ' Segment 1 ', ' Segment 2 ', ' Segment 3']
```

the above works fine but won't be able to handle `str_2`. If I made the third pair of numbers  , it just returns the optional group

```
re.findall(r'\d\d?:\d\d?(:\d\d?)?', str_1)
=> [':00', ':00', ':00']

re.split(r'\d\d?:\d\d?(:\d\d?)?', str_1)
=> ['', ':00', ' Segment 1 ', ':00', ' Segment 2 ', ':00', ' Segment 3']

re.findall(r'\d\d?:\d\d?(:\d\d?)?', str_2)
=> ['', '']

re.split(r'\d\d?:\d\d?(:\d\d?)?', str_2)
=> ['', None, ' Segment 1 ', None, ' Segment 2']
```

However, if I made the optional group without capturing, `str_2` works fine but results are mixed with `str_1`

```
re.findall(r'\d\d?:\d\d?(?:\d\d?)?', str_1)
=> ['00:00', '00:20', '8:00']

re.split(r'\d\d?:\d\d?(?:\d\d?)?', str_1)
=> ['', ':00 Segment 1 ', ':00 Segment 2 ', ':00 Segment 3']

re.findall(r'\d\d?:\d\d?(?:\d\d?)?', str_2)
=> ['00:00', '20:0']

re.split(r'\d\d?:\d\d?(?:\d\d?)?', str_2)
=> ['', ' Segment 1 ', ' Segment 2']
```

I want to find a regex which works fine on both `str_` and `str_2`, kind of have the optional group but without the capturing effect. Anyway to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the `:` in your pattern; you need two, one for the `?:` and one for your literal `:`, ala:

```
re.findall(r'\d\d?:\d\d?(?::\d\d?)?', str_1)
=> ['00:00:00', '00:20:00', '8:00:00']
```